# Custom hashmap with 2 value fields VS implement a hashmap with an array as value in java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hash, hashmap

Are they added benefits to writing my own hash map data structure instead of using a pre written class like hashmap in java.

Background.
Im writing a spring application that requires data structure that can map a single key to map to two values.

the current benefits i can think of now will be:
- can include more methods such as swap (swap value 1 with 2)
- more control over hashing functions
- more control in general

was wondering:
- if they are any draw backs in terms of performance or complexity
- or if it makes any sense at all to write my own data structure

Thanks for taking the time to read.

EDIT:
If it helps helps.
i only need fast access speed (methods like get and contains)
for methods that "put", time taken can be a little longer
Any suggestion on what i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You risk missing out on a very *well-vetted, proven and durable* framework by not using the `java.util` package. No offense, but it's unlikely you're going to come up with a better design and implementation, especially one as bug-free and optimized as part of Java's core API. Rather, use what exists and either write your own small methods, extend the existing HashMap, or find another open-source variant (e.g. maybe from [Apache FastHashMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.html)) to get the additional required functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple: Use `HashMap` whose value type is a simple class to hold two values, eg (for simplicity, I have assumed key and both values are String):

```
class Pair {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    public Pair(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void swap() {
        // Note: Not threadsafe
        String tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Pair
            && Objects.equals(a, ((Pair)o).a
            && Objects.equals(b, ((Pair)o).b;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(a, b);
    }
}

Map<String, Pair> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Good post but in the interest of "keeping things simple", I would remove the `synchronized` keyword. It doesn't add any benefit anyhow if the getters aren't synchronized; updates using the swap method are not guaranteed to be visible in another thread if there is no happens-before relationship between the threads.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt fair enough. It was more an indicator that swapping isn't atomic. I removed synchronized.